# Filter array by values below specific number

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I have this array:

```
let numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

And I want to append all numbers below 6 in this array below:

```
var belowSix = [Int]()
```

Here is what I have done and it works:

```
for number in numbers {
    if number < 6 {
        belowSix.append(number)
    }
}
```

**Question:**
It feels like this can be done in a smoother way, any suggestions?

Comment: Is the array always sorted?

Comment: @EricAya, yes it is

Comment: @SameSome What if your number array is `[0,1,2,3,4,2,5,6,7,8,9]` in this case it will not show `5` in your `belowSix` array if you use `prefix(6)` so better if you use `filter` not the `prefix` because prefix is used to get specific objects from array starting

Comment: @SameSome Have you tried `prefix(6)` with array `[0,1,2,3,4,2,5,6,7,8,9]`, You will not get your desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You can use [`filter`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688383-filter) for that.

```
let belowSix = numbers.filter { $0 < 6 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want (up to) first 6 elements:

```
var belowSix = numbers.prefix(6)
```

If you want to get all elements below 6 use:

```
let belowSix = numbers.filter { $0 < 6 }
```

Comment: If the array is not sorted (and if does not contain all numbers), then `prefix(6)` won't work.

Comment: As OP wrote it always is.

Comment: Try this on an array with duplicates, even if it is sorted - say, `[1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5]`

Comment: Also what if array is having less object than 6 like [2,5,6,7,8]

Comment: @NiravD, then it will show all the values if it´s below.